# Custom SeekBar like SeekBar in Swipe menu IOS 11

Tags: android, styles, seekbar

I am creating app for android with IOS style.
Now, I am adding SeekBar to activity.
How to create SeekBar like SeekBar in Swipe menu IOS 11.
[image]
Pleace help me:)

Comment: https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar this is not a seek bar. This will help to make your seek bar like this

Answer (score 1):

I found.
Here  is answer.
This is custom view, SeekBar like iOS swipe menu 
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6291#!description